# Objective C error when playing multiple sounds

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am trying to play many sounds using AVAudioPlayer and foundation.
The code is this

```
- (IBAction)pushButton19 {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The Terminator" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

- (IBAction)pushButton20 {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The Wizard of Oz" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

on the line `theAudio.delegate = self;`
it says

> class * does not implement the
>   protocol

as well as

> Semantic Issue Assigning to ID
>    from
>   incompatible type MainView *

what do i need to do to fix it and can u show me the correct code as im a noob at this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller must conforms to the [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and implements its necessary methods. [This is a sample code for playing sound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845).